# Tiny single Bidirectional layer big RAM usage?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

I have several different small models 1-2MB size on disk, some are just fully connected layers, Transformer, and a couple of Bidirectional GRU networks. But they have very different memory requirements when I load them in TensorFlow Serving.

Does anyone know why the Bidirectional GRU network a very simple one shown below takes >100MB to load compared to a Transformer with several layers and double the number of weights which only takes half the RAM of 50MB to load, (the fully connected networks are very small 5-10MB RAM).

```
 vocab_size = 200
 embedding_dim = 32
 enc_units = 64

 self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
 gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(enc_units, 
    return_sequences=True, 
    recurrent_initializer="glorot_uniform",
  )
 self.bidi = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(gru, merge_mode="concat")
```

Any way to reduce the RAM requirements for the network?

I tried reducing the enc_units from 64 to 32, same for embedding_dim 64->32, but that didn't change the RAM usage at all.